# spring cloud data flow starter apps - Possibility to Add Custom Code

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using SCDF starter apps, such as 'file' source, in my data pipeline.
Is there a way to add my custom code on top, such as by using callbacks or hooks?

For example, one use case I want to address: 
I would like to log the details of every file processed to a database.

Thank You in advance.

Regards
GS

Comment: Check this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-data-flow-stream-processing

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are dataflow taps - ability to tap into your stream of data and do "as you wish" with the data.
You can read up more on it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-dsl-tap)

Comment: You can also patch the existing app starters by following this procedure described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications
That way you can add your own custom behavior to the file source.

Comment: I'm trying out the tap option as @Oleg-Zhurakousky suggested.